# Transform table into another table (data in rows into columns)

Tags: r, dataframe

I am relatively new to R. I made some analyses on the observer XT software (software for video coding of behaviors). For other analyses, I have to transform the exported text file (i.e. the table) in another form.

The table extracted from the observer XT looks like this :

| Datetime | Behavior | Event Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30-07-2020 23:12:23 | browsing | State start |
| 30-07-2020 23:14:30 | browsing | State stop |
| 30-07-2020 23:16:04 | browsing | State start |
| 30-07-2020 23:16:05 | browsing | State stop |

Here you can see that each row shows the beginning or the end of a behavior.

My goal is to take two by two each line and create a begin / stop line like this.

| Start_Datetime | Stop_Datetime | Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30-07-2020 23:12:23 | 30-07-2020 23:14:30 | browsing |
| 30-07-2020 23:16:04 | 30-07-2020 23:17:05 | browsing |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create a group of every 2 rows and cast the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(row = ceiling(row_number()/2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Event.Type  , values_from = Datetime) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row) -> result

result

#  Behavior `State start`       `State stop`       
#  <chr>    <chr>               <chr>              
#1 browsing 30-07-2020 23:12:23 30-07-2020 23:14:30
#2 browsing 30-07-2020 23:16:04 30-07-2020 23:16:05
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Datetime = c("30-07-2020 23:12:23", "30-07-2020 23:14:30", 
"30-07-2020 23:16:04", "30-07-2020 23:16:05"), Behavior = c("browsing", 
"browsing", "browsing", "browsing"), Event.Type = c("State start", 
"State stop", "State start", "State stop")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option using `dcast` (thank @Ronak Shah for data)

```
dcast(
  setDT(df),
  Behavior + rowid(Event.Type) ~ Event.Type,
  value.var = "Datetime"
)[
  , Event.Type := NULL
][]
```

which gives

```
   Behavior         State start          State stop
1: browsing 30-07-2020 23:12:23 30-07-2020 23:14:30
2: browsing 30-07-2020 23:16:04 30-07-2020 23:16:05
```